# How do I set a table with different amount of columns on each row?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am just learning about iText7 but I can't seem to fix the layout of my table.
I have drawn what I wanted in paint just to show you (don't hate on my paint skills please :P).

[image: Table]

Just for information:

- The first row will be a text.
- The second row will be first a text then a picture.
- Then a small line of text.
- Then a piece of text and a picture next to it.

Somehow my first row keeps setting the width of all cells below.

I tried using a normal cell and a headercell but I keep getting the same results.

```
    private void TestPDF()
    {
        var CustomSize= new Rectangle(241, 142);
        var writer = new PdfWriter("Test " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyy") + ".pdf");
        var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        var document = new Document(pdf, new PageSize(CustomSize));
        document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        var tableinformatie = new Table(2);
        tableinformatie.SetWidth(241);
        tableinformatie.SetHeight(142);
        tableinformatie.SetPadding(0);
        tableinformatie.AddHeaderCell("test").UseAllAvailableWidth();
        tableinformatie.AddCell("test").SetWidth(241);
        tableinformatie.AddCell("test").SetWidth(100);

        document.Add(tableinformatie);
        document.Close();
    }
```

This is my code so far and I tried playing around with a fixed layout. Setting the width and height of each individual cell but it didn't work.

I must be overlooking something.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

I played around with the idea of multiple tables instead of fixing it with 1 table. And this worked out for me :)!

```
private void StickerInMM()
{
        var Sticker = new Rectangle(241, 142);
        var writer = new PdfWriter("Test " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyy") + ".pdf");
        var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        var document = new Document(pdf, new PageSize(Sticker));
        document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);


        ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.Create("c:/Users/Public/Cyaan.jpg");
        Image img = new Image(data);
        img.SetHeight(15);

        ImageData data2 = ImageDataFactory.Create("c:/Users/Public/Tekst.jpg");
        Image img2 = new Image(data2);
        img2.ScaleToFit(100, 100);

        var EANFONT = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("c:/Users/Public/ean13.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
        var cellean = new Paragraph(richTextBox2.Text)
            .SetFontSize(38)
            .SetFont(EANFONT);

        var table = new Table(new float[] { 1 });
        table.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
        table.AddCell("Laser toner cartridge");
        document.Add(table);

        var table2 = new Table(new float[] { 3, 1 });
        table2.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
        table2.AddCell("Test");
        table2.AddCell(img);
        document.Add(table2);

        var table3 = new Table(new float[] { 1 });
        table3.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
        table3.AddCell("Test");
        document.Add(table3);

        var table4 = new Table(new float[] { 2, 2 });
        table4.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
        table4.AddCell(img2);          
        table4.AddCell(cellean);
        document.Add(table4);

        document.Close();
    }
```

This now creates the correct table with the right sizes.

Thank you Paulo Soares for the idea.

Comment: What you want is not a table but a collection of stacked tables. You can play around with column span but it may be easier to use more than one table.

Comment: That is great work around, but it leaves me with a white space between the tables. Not sure on how to get that out :S

Comment: Please make your edit with the solution an actual answer to your question (not an edit to the question) which you then can accept.

Comment: [Tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"The **only time** you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void StickerInMM()
{
        var Sticker = new Rectangle(241, 142);
        var writer = new PdfWriter("Test " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyy") + ".pdf");
        var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        var document = new Document(pdf, new PageSize(Sticker));
        document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);


        ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.Create("c:/Users/Public/Cyaan.jpg");
        Image img = new Image(data);
        img.SetHeight(15);

        ImageData data2 = ImageDataFactory.Create("c:/Users/Public/Tekst.jpg");
        Image img2 = new Image(data2);
        img2.ScaleToFit(100, 100);

        var EANFONT = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("c:/Users/Public/ean13.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
        var cellean = new Paragraph(richTextBox2.Text)
            .SetFontSize(38)
            .SetFont(EANFONT);

        var table = new Table(new float[] { 1 });
        table.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
        table.AddCell("Laser toner cartridge");
        document.Add(table);

        var table2 = new Table(new float[] { 3, 1 });
        table2.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
        table2.AddCell("Test");
        table2.AddCell(img);
        document.Add(table2);

        var table3 = new Table(new float[] { 1 });
        table3.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
        table3.AddCell("Test");
        document.Add(table3);

        var table4 = new Table(new float[] { 2, 2 });
        table4.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
        table4.AddCell(img2);          
        table4.AddCell(cellean);
        document.Add(table4);

        document.Close();
    }
```

Fixed it with the code above :D !